# Nepal: How bad is the rainy season?

Tags: seasonal, weather-and-climate, nepal

I'm considering a trip to Nepal next week, which will mean I would arrive in early July which I've found out is the rainy season. I would be planning to stay for about 2 months, hopefully having enough time to get around the country a bit and really get a feel for the culture.

**But, I've found out that this is the middle of the rainy season (i.e. monsoon season).**

What I haven't been able to find out is just how bad the rainy season really is, and what that might mean for my trip. The only information I've been able to find pertains specifically to trekking in the raining season, but I'm more curious about the country in general, and will be perfectly happy if trekking isn't an option.

What I want to ask is, how much does it rain in Nepal during the rainy season? Does it rain virtually non-stop, or does it just rain an hour or two each afternoon? Will my trip be constantly interrupted by rain, or is there still a lot to do in Nepal during the monsoon season?

Comment: http://wikitravel.org/en/Nepal may help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this year (2013) at the time of writing it appears that Nepal is raining heavily each and every day, virtually all day, my research shows that this is not typical. Typically during the monsoon season, it appears to rain for several hours each afternoon/evening and in fact if trekking is not your goal this seems to have the benefit of reducing dust/pollution in the cities, making the air much clearer.  In addition the late monsoon season of August/September hosts most of Nepal's cultural festivals, so although I have yet to visit, it appears that if culture experience rather than trekking is your goal the late Monsoon season may even be the very best time to visit Nepal.

Some good information can be found on wikitravel as mentioned, and here as well: http://www.wayfarers.com.np/trekking/monsoon_nepal.htm